# How to add calendar icon on GridView::widget filter textbox?

Tags: gridview, yii2, widget

I would like to add a calendar icon in GridView::widget filter text box as mentioned in the image given below. I have tried too many ways but works as well. Please my view page code also.

[image]

Please see the above image and I want to make the "Launch Date" filter text box as circled in the image. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Please see my view page code for the same.

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    
                <?= GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                        'columns' => [
                            [
                                'attribute' => 'entity_id',
                                'value' => function($model) {
                                    return $model->entity->title;
                                },
                            ],
                            'leave_title',
                            [
                                'attribute' => 'leave_configuration_id',
                                'value' => function($model) {
                                    return $model->leaveConfiguration->title;
                                },
                            ],
                            [
                                'attribute' => 'emp_type',
                                'filter' => \app\models\SbhrmEmployee::typeOptions(),
                                'value' => function($model) {
                                    return $model->getEmployeeType();
                                },
                            ],
                            [
                                'attribute' => 'launch_date',
                                //'template' => "{label}{input}<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback'></span>",
                                'value' => function($model) {
                                    return date('d M, Y',strtotime($model->launch_date));
                                },
                                'filter' => DatePicker::widget([
                                    'model' => $searchModel,
                                    'attribute' => 'launch_date',
                                    'options' => [
                                        'autocomplete' => 'off',
                                        'class' => 'form-control',
                                        'template' => "{label}{input}<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback'></span>"
                                    ],
                                    //'template' => "{label}{input}<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback'></span>",
                                    'clientOptions' => [
                                        'orientation' => 'bottom auto',
                                        "format" => "dd M, yyyy",
                                        "orientation" =>'bottom',
                                        "autoclose" => true, 
                                        "todayHighlight"=> true,
                                    ],
                                    'dateFormat' => 'php:d M, Y'
                                ]),
                            ],

                            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'header' => 'Actions'],
                        ],
                    ]); ?>
                <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: So this `DatePicker` widget you are using is not adding the calendar icon like you want? What is this package exactly?

Comment: Package i am using is https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-jui

Comment: Have you considered https://demosbs3.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker ?

Answer (score 0):

DateColumn:
https://gist.github.com/uldisn/804f46a7a0f98a60c580d40526dfeae7

EaDtateRangePicker:
https://gist.github.com/uldisn/ad1b6e234db2cb8df66072ccf8c4dd22

Grid columns

```
        [
            'class' => ThDateColumn::class,
            'attribute' => 'doc_date',
        ],
```

Query for filtering:
https://github.com/d3yii2/d3system/blob/master/yii2/db/D3ActiveQuery.php

In Search:

```
$query->andFilterWhereDateRange('doc_date',$this->doc_date);
```